# Dependency to numpy cannot be resolved when installing requirements.txt in Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure, numpy, pip, azure-functions

My azure function is using python module `pywavelets` which requires dependency to `numpy`. Here is my `requirements.txt`

```
azure-functions

cloudpickle==0.5.3
cycler==0.10.0
dask==0.18.2
decorator==4.3.0
kiwisolver==1.0.1
matplotlib==2.2.3
networkx==2.1
numpy==1.15.0
Pillow==5.2.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.7.3
pytz==2018.5
PyWavelets==0.5.2
scikit-image==0.14.0
scipy==1.1.0
six==1.11.0
termcolor==1.1.0
toolz==0.9.0
wget==3.2
nltk
pdfminer
sumy
```

But I encountered the `ModuleNotFound` error from `pywavelets` when the function is tested locally:

```
Requirement already satisfied: azure-functions in ./.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (1.6.0)
Collecting cloudpickle==0.5.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/bf/60ae7ec1e8c6742d2abbb6819c39a48ee796793bcdb7e1d5e41a3e379ddd/cloudpickle-0.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cycler==0.10.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/d2/e07d3ebb2bd7af696440ce7e754c59dd546ffe1bbe732c8ab68b9c834e61/cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting dask==0.18.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/91/52/427541141707ac533a6dcafa3bff7ff8b57ded3c9ea84d6ec014d15fbbff/dask-0.18.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting decorator==4.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/bb/a24838832ba35baf52f32ab1a49b906b5f82fb7c76b2f6a7e35e140bac30/decorator-4.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting kiwisolver==1.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/60/494fcce70d60a598c32ee00e71542e52e27c978e5f8219fae0d4ac6e2864/kiwisolver-1.0.1.tar.gz
Collecting matplotlib==2.2.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/eb/a0/31b6ba00bc4dcbc06f0b80d1ad6119a9cc3081ecb04a00117f6c1ca3a084/matplotlib-2.2.3.tar.gz
Collecting networkx==2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/42/f951cc6838a4dff6ce57211c4d7f8444809ccbe2134179950301e5c4c83c/networkx-2.1.zip
Collecting numpy==1.15.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/20/c81632328b1a4e1db65f45c0a1350a9c5341fd4bbb8ea66cdd98da56fe2e/numpy-1.15.0.zip
Collecting Pillow==5.2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d3/c4/b45b9c0d549f482dd072055e2d3ced88f3b977f7b87c7a990228b20e7da1/Pillow-5.2.0.tar.gz
Collecting pyparsing==2.2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/8a/718fd7d3458f9fab8e67186b00abdd345b639976bc7fb3ae722e1b026a50/pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil==2.7.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/f5/af2b09c957ace60dcfac112b669c45c8c97e32f94aa8b56da4c6d1682825/python_dateutil-2.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz==2018.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 18))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/4e/27c34b62430286c6d59177a0842ed90dc789ce5d1ed740887653b898779a/pytz-2018.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting PyWavelets==0.5.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 19))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/df/3fff2a8b96ef7df6e4e8642fb7569c3717ae562dd76afe0f96525c0af784/PyWavelets-0.5.2.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/chaozy/Desktop/textSum/.venv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/7m/tzzll84901gdl2lvrjb4cxkh0000gn/T/pip-install-krw2z9vf/PyWavelets/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/7m/tzzll84901gdl2lvrjb4cxkh0000gn/T/pip-install-krw2z9vf/PyWavelets/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/7m/tzzll84901gdl2lvrjb4cxkh0000gn/T/pip-install-krw2z9vf/PyWavelets/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/7m/tzzll84901gdl2lvrjb4cxkh0000gn/T/pip-install-krw2z9vf/PyWavelets/setup.py", line 12, in <module>
        from numpy import get_include as get_numpy_include
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

But as we can see from the ouput, `numpy` has been installed prior to `PyWavelets`.

How can I resolve this problem? Many thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Here is the only python script `__init__.py` in my code:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('This function processes a request.')
    # I comment out all the remaining stuff
```

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: @BowmanZhu I have tested it without one line of code but the error still exists. So I think it is a pure pip installation problem.

Comment: May I know if you have a line of code `import numpy` before the line `from numpy import get_include as get_numpy_include` ?

Comment: @HuryShen I am currently using the default `__init__.py` , which only contains the import to `azure.functions as func`. There is no other code anymore. I will updated my OP with the `__init__.py`.

Comment: Could you please try to run the function in another terminal window, please click "Terminal" --> "New Terminal".

Comment: @HuryShen I tried with a new terminal window. It has no problem when I run the program with `func start` ( I can't see the pip installing process from this command). But when I tried to deploy it to azure by `func azure functionapp publish {FunctionName}` it still returned the same error.

Comment: @HuryShen Running the program locally by `ctrl + F5` still returns the same error

Comment: Could you please kill the terminal window which you used in the past ? Or if you do not know how to kill them, you can also create another new function app in your VS code on local.

Comment: @HuryShen I tried with both kill the terminal and create a new function app, they all failed with the same error as the previous one.

Comment: I will do some test and back if I find something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test in my side with same modules as yours in my `requirements.txt` and run the function with Ctrl + F5. It shows same error message as you mentioned.

It seems there are some conflicts of the two modules(in the versions which you specified in your `requirements.txt`). To solve this problem, just remove the version of the two modules in `requirements.txt`. Below is my `requirements.txt`:

[image]

If we do not specify the version, it will install the latest version automatically. In my function app, it intalls `numpy 1.20.0` and `PyWavelets 1.1.1`, and the function runs success when I use Ctrl + F5.